# Powershell. Как выполнить экспорт полученного массива в Excel?

Tags: excel, powershell

Добрый день.
Выполняю парсинг с помощью Powershell+Selenium.
С помощью команды `$fullstory = $ie.FindElementByClassName("comment")`

Получаю вывод:

```
Исполнитель: Pink Floyd
Название альбома: Dark Side Of the Moon
Стиль: Rock
Год выпуска: 2016
```

Как сделать вывод Excel чтобы соответственно "Исполнитель:", "Название альбома:" и.т.д стали столбцами, а то что после двоеточия - значениями столбцом?
Спасибо заранее.

Comment: excel пишется с "с", зачем ошибки в метках делать.

Answer (score 3):

Можете вывести все в Csv файл, а затем открыть его через  Excel

```
$fullstory | Export-Csv .\out.csv -Delimiter ":" -NoTypeInformation
Invoke-Item .\out.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$obj = New-Object PSObject
foreach ($i in ($fullstory -match '\w+')){
   $row = @($i -split ':')
   $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty $row[0].Trim() $row[1].Trim()
}
$obj | Export-Csv ("{0}\csv.csv" -f $env:TEMP) -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8
& ("{0}\csv.csv" -f $env:TEMP)
```

Answer (score -1):

Я бы делал так:

- Создаем пустой Эксель-файл, выставляем нужную ширину столбцов.
- Копируем наш пустой-файл с новым именем.
- Открываем эксель файл-с-новым-именем.
- Записываем в него данные.
- Закрываем файл.